# Struts:サーバーが停止している場合に、サーバー停止中画面(html)に遷移したい

Tags: tomcat, struts

Strutsを使用しています。 
サーバー内のJSPにアクセスし、サーバーが停止している(ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSEDの)場合はサーバー停止中画面(html)に遷移したいのですが、方法が分かりません。 
現在は、Tomcatのメンテナンスﾓｰﾄﾞについて調査中ですが、まだ解決には至っていません。 
解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

掲載：[teratail 「 Struts:サーバーが停止している場合に、サーバー停止中画面(html)に遷移したい 」](https://teratail.com/questions/17290)

Comment: 「サーバーが停止している」という表現が曖昧で、どういう状態を指しているのか今ひとつはっきりしません。どういうサーバー構成になっているのか、TomcatやStrutsのバージョンは何か、Apache等との連携はあるのか、その構成において「サーバーが停止している」とは具体的にどういう状況を指しているのか、を追記していただけませんか。

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`というのは、[Chromeがエラー102を返している](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/117805?hl=ja)状態ということでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcatを停止している状態で、HTTPリクエストに対して「サーバー停止中画面」を表示するには、ApacheなどのHTTPサーバーが必要です。Tomcatを止めて、Apacheを動かして あらゆるリクエストに対して 決まった HTML を返せば良いと思います。

また、OS を停止している状態の場合は、「サーバー停止中画面」専用のWebサーバを別途用意して、DNSレコードを書き換えて 向き先を変更する手法があります。

(ご参考までに追記) 他にも手法はあるので ソーリーサーバー、ソーリーページ などで検索すると色々情報が得られると思います。